# Scale CASE WHEN to retrieve non-holiday dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, exists

I have table containing records with start and end dates, so I have to grab every record that started on a Friday, and if any Friday is a holiday, get Thursday, and if Friday and Thursday are holidays, get Wednesday and so on...

Currently I have two tables `TableA` for the records and `Calendar` to get holidays.

My `TableA` look like this:

```
id beg         end
--------------------------
1  11/01/2019  14/01/2019
2  10/01/2019  14/01/2019
3  09/01/2019  15/01/2019
...
```

Calendar looks like this:

```
iddate    date        weekday isholiday
---------------------------------------
20190109  09/01/2019  3       0 --0=False / 1=True
20190110  10/01/2019  4       0
20190111  11/01/2019  5       1
...
```

For both tables I use `WHERE EXISTS` to get Fridays and the holiday conditional which actually displays results:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.Calendar AS c
              WHERE c.date = CAST(t.BEG AS DATETIME)
                AND c.weekday = CASE
                                    WHEN (C.weekday = 5 AND C.isholiday = 0)  
                                       THEN 5 --keep friday
                                    --WHEN ((C.weekday= 4 AND C.isholiday= 1) OR (C.weekday= 5 AND C.isholiday= 1)) THEN 3 --keep wednesday / not working
                                       ELSE 4 --keep thursday
                                    END
                AND DATEPART(yyyy, T.beg) = 2019)
ORDER BY 
    CAST(INI AS [datetime])
```

If Friday is a holiday, it will display this:

```
id beg         end
--------------------------
2  10/01/2019  14/01/2019
3  09/01/2019  15/01/2019
```

If Friday and Thursday are holidays, it should display:

```
id beg         end
--------------------------
3  09/01/2019  15/01/2019
```

Scaling it up with this `WHEN ((C.weekday= 4 AND C.isholiday= 1) OR (C.weekday= 5 AND C.isholiday= 1))` just breaks the entire query and I get -almost- random dates. Any way to scaling it up without extending the query too much?

Comment: Is your Calendar table complete, in the sense that there are 365 rows for the year 2019?  Also, your expected results don't match your initial description - the section labeled "If Friday was a holiday" includes an event from Wednesday, even though Thursday is not a holiday  Could you please clarify?  Finally, what version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: @Brian Yes, it has 30 years of data. I mean that I need every row from the last working day for each week, so if friday it's a holiday on the calendar table the last working day will be on thursday and I'm on SQL Server 2008. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I would use a common table expression:

```
;With cte_Last_Day_Of_Week
As
(
    Select 
        c.iddate
        , c.date
        , Row_Number() Over (Partition By DatePart(Week, c.date) Order By c.date Desc) As RN
    From dbo.Calendar As c
    Where c.isholiday = 0
)
```

The `Row_Number()` will flag the date of the last non-holiday day in each week with a value of `1`.  You can then join against that as you would a table.

Let me know if that makes sense.